# Factorial in Scientific notation

Tags: java, types, scientific-notation

I want to show factorial of a number in scientific notation.

For example - `100! = "9.332621544e+157"`

Is there any other way to do this besides `NumberFormat`? This is my code so far -

```
BigDecimal res=new BigDecimal("1");
for(int i=2;i<=x;i++){
   res=res.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i));
}
str=String.valueOf(res+"");
display.setText(str);
```

I'm really sorry if this question is vague to understand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with NumberFormat?

Comment: my teacher didn't teach that.... so i can't use it in my project  :)

Comment: so it must be an homemade solution right?

Comment: only if there isn't any other way to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not nice but changing

```
str=String.valueOf(res+"");
```

to

```
String str=res.doubleValue()+"";
```

will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Using NumberFormat is the way to go but if you don't want to use that you could use a [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

See [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more info